# Simulate User Click Event with JavaScript on Bootstrap Button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How can i simulate with Javascript the click Event of a Bootstrap Button to perform the default actions that binded on the Button ?

I need this for automated Testing of a website.

Bootstrap add no Event on the Button himself, the events a bubbled to the body element and the work is done their.

$("btn.btn-outline-danger").click() is not working
$("btn.btn-outline-danger").trigger("click") is not working

Comment: I believe `$("btn.btn-outline-danger").click()` should work if jQuery is loaded. It would help if you provided a bit of html code.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn',function(){
    alert('click');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Your suggestion adds its own event handler, which I can trigger with .click () - unfortunately this does not trigger the already existing click events that run through the bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

Since Bootstrap uses jQuery as a dependency you can simulate a click event in jQuery way.

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
  console.log('Event Triggered');
});
```

Excluding jQuery, Vanillajs.

```
var button = document.getElementByClassName('.btn');
button.onclick = console.log('Event Triggered');
```

Comment: Your code binds code to the button. OP asks about triggering a click event with code, thus simulating a click. jQuery click() (without a function between the brackets) does this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - Your suggestion adds its own event handler, which I can trigger with .click () - unfortunately this does not trigger the already existing click events that run through the bootstrap framework.

Answer (score 0):

Events should bubble up to the parent (unless explicitly prevented). Consider this simple html structure:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

With the code below the parent has a function attached to the click event. When the child click event is triggered, the parent's event responds.

```
$(".parent").click(function() {alert("hello")}); // attach event
$(".child").click(); // trigger event
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/epqdz2a1/](http://jsfiddle)

This should be the same in Bootstrap.

Vanilla js version:

```
document.querySelector(".parent").addEventListener("click", function(){alert("hello")});
document.querySelector(".child").click();
```

Comment: Event Bubbling does not work if a add my own click event to the Bootstrap Button :-(